# Redirect after user switching (impersonating) in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, impersonation

I searched everywhere but it seems impossible thing to do.

I was able to catch `SwitchEvent` coming from `SwitchEventListener` and get both impersonator and target user objects (one being impersonated as) but I would really like, based on target user roles to redirect request to some other URL.

Example:

I have two restricted areas: "/basic" and "/elevated" where first one requires `ROLE_BASIC` and the other one `ROLE_ELEVATED` role. Now, if I am currently logged in as `ROLE_ELEVATED` user and want to switch to some `ROLE_BASIC` user using URL:

```
/basic/?_switch_user=some_basic_user
```

that would result in **AccessDeniedException**, and I'm forced to navigate first to:

```
/?_switch_user=some_basic_user.
```

Only after that I can navigate to /basic as token has been written to session.

Now, **the question**, as subject suggests: Is there any way to redirect user using `SwitchEvent` (or any other) after doing user switching?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I'm having the same issue. It seems that `AccessListener` is called before `SwitchUserListener` so you're locked out before the `SwitchUser` can be invoked?

Comment: Actually, I did :) Currently, I don't have access to my dev computer but as I do (tomorrow or day after that) I going to write here how I did it. BTW, thanks for reminding me about posted question. I totally forgot I asked it so I definitely need to "close" it with an appropriate answer...

Comment: I'm very interested in your solution too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I finally got access to my dev computer and looked up the the solution to this problem.

And, I got to say, it is not as clean as I wanted it to be but delivery date was critical and this was the only way to achieve it back then.

So, what I basically did was to send AJAX (although, I set `async` to `false`) request to URL `/?_switch_user=some_basic_user`, wait for an answer and if it was successful I would navigate forward to `/basic/?_switch_user=some_basic_user` URL. I know, it's quick and dirty, and is pretty much unreliable...

Hope this helps....

Comment: Nice solution, little hacky but worked for me. I wish there was a redirect path built in

Answer (score 0):

You can just generate the right link to begin with:

```
<a href="/basic/?_switch_user=some_basic_user">...</a>
```

Of course, the URL can be generated by twig's `path` helper too:

```
<a href="{{ path('basic_homepage', { _switch_user: 'some_basic_user' }) }}">...</a>
```

Comment: Quoting the question: that would result in AccessDeniedException